# How can I incorporate an LDR in a 555 flasher circuit?

Tags: led, 555, ldr, multivibrator

[image: 555 Bi Flasher Circuit]

I have designed this flasher circuit using a 555. I want to incorporate a light dependent resistor (LDR) to start flashing the LEDs only when it is dark. I can't figure out where I should put the LDR to get this thing working properly.

Comment: Bhargav Rajyaguru - Hi, (a) As you are new here, please see the [tour] & [help] for the main site rules & etiquette, and to see how Stack Exchange differs from typical forums. (b) You said that you designed the above circuit, but the image seems to be copied from someone else's page [here](https://www.instructables.com/Eren-Yeager-PCB-ART/) (specifically [this one](https://content.instructables.com/FIC/CW13/KZZKKAH1/FICCW13KZZKKAH1.jpg?auto=webp&frame=1&width=839&height=601&fit=bounds&md=02ef4492604a985b402176a6c9a9bbb6)). Did you mean that you're trying to build their one?

Comment: @SamGibson I believe that instructable you've linked to is just that guy soldering the board he designed off the schematic from someone else. See how the schematic says "5 to 10V", but the board uses a single CR2032 (3V) lithium cell? So, this is a schematic stolen by the instructable author, who then acted as if he had the copyright to it and put it under the CC-by-SA license, which of course would have meant that Bhargav here is totally free to use it, as long as they cited the original author… yeah. So, this probably a schematic stolen all the way down to some poor …

Comment: … magazine author in the late 1970s.

Comment: anyways, the question is really too broad without demonstrating any own attempt. As far as I can tell, the only sensible way to shut off both LEDs would be to disconnect the whole circuit from VCC, or disconnect the top LED from VCC *and* pull the 555's output low. In either case, the modification to the circuit would be significant enough to warrant just throwing out this approach, and replacing it with something that involves digital logic, as switching something on or off both at discrete times ("blinking") and based on a binary condition ("is it dark enough") is a digital control problem.

Comment: @SamGibson Respected Sir, I kept that schematic only for the reference. What I meant there, I have designed the same circuit in EasyEDA but unfortunately I didn't post it here and I am sorry for it. But I have tried lot of ways but couldn't succeed to turn the complete circuit off using an LDR.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Respected Sir, Thank you very much for your explanation. I am still trying and will also post my solution here, if I will be able to find it.

Answer (score 1):

You can stop the operation of circuit by changing the state of reset pin of 555. However, that will cause LED 1 to remain on as long as the circuit is powered up but put in reset condition.

The only other way I could see this working was to incorporate an op-amp based voltage comparator circuit to trigger power to the 555 circuit by using a transistor.

Here is an example circuit that I made to help you understand better.

[image: Comparator circuit]

Notice that I have not added any values for resistances and transistor as you will have to calculate them according to your own requirements. This circuit might need modifications but still should serve as a good starting point.

Edit: Now that I gave it another thought, you can also use a simple voltage divider using LDR and get rid of the op-amp circuit as you only want to turn a transistor on and off. Here's what I mean.

[image: Voltage divider circuit]